# Plotting with arbitrary units

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot, say, Sin[x/a] with multiples "a" showing on the x axis as units. How can I do that ?

I have tried setting the plot limits e.g. {x, -2a, 2a}. I cannot plot said function even with limits as {x, -2, 2}.

How does one plot functions with parameters ?

Comment: Did you take a look at the _extensive_ help for `Plot` yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`Ticks`-option](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html) of `Plot` for this:

Example: `a=\[Pi]`

```
With[{a = \[Pi]}, 
 Plot[Sin[x/a], {x, -2 a, 2 a}, 
  Ticks -> {Range[-2 a, 2 a, a], Automatic}]]
```

gives

[image: new ticks]

For "real" quantities, this can be adapted straightforward to display the unit in the ticks:

```
With[{a = Quantity["Meters"]},
 Plot[Sin[x/a], {x, -2 a, 2 a}, 
  Ticks -> {{QuantityMagnitude@#, #} & /@ Range[-2 a, 2 a, a], 
   Automatic}]]
```

[image: ticks with units]

Comment: Hello, could you make this work with arbitrary units ?
Where can I find the extensive help ? Thank you.

Comment: @joo: Ever pressed F1 in *Mathematica*? See [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) and [units](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Units.html).

Comment: I regarded that as the regular help. As I found no help with my problem there, I asked here. My question stands - how is it possible to make a plot with "a" showing as the units ? Thanks.

Comment: @joo: Take a look at the option [`Ticks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html) to `Plot` in that documentation. I will amdend my answer to that regard shortly.

Comment: likewise `Ticks -> {{#, StringJoin@ {ToString@#, " a"} } & /@ Range[-2 , 2 ]` in case your "unit" is not something `Quantity` knows